# GUI won't run correct unless radio buttons are cycled through

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I've created a GUI that estimates the materials and pricing involved in building a home given a few criteria provided in ui panels with radio buttons as options. The problem is that hitting the go button for the GUI throws errors unless the radio buttons are played with first. I cannot leave my buttons on the selection that they are when the GUI is run. How can I run the .m file and then hit go on the .fig without having to touch anything (aside from filling in the square footage edit box)?

```
 function uibuttongroup3_SelectionChangedFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to the selected object in uibuttongroup3 
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
tag = eventdata.NewValue;
switch get(tag,'Tag')
case 'OneHalfBath'
    BathRoom = 1
case 'TwoHalfBath'
    BathRoom = 2
case 'ThreeHalfBath'
    BathRoom = 3
end;
if BathRoom == 1
    BathWall = 30
    BathSq = 36
elseif BathRoom == 2
    BathWall = 48
    BathSq = 72
    elseif BathRoom == 3
    BathWall = 66
    BathSq = 108
end;
setappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathWall',BathWall);
setappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathSq',BathSq);
setappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathRoom',BathRoom);
```

The above is one of four UI panels with radio buttons, just for an example. All are written roughly the same way. Snippets of the go button callback are below.

```
function GoBut_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to GoBut (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
run('UrlPrice.m');
BathRoom = getappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathRoom');
BathSq = getappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathSq');
BathWall = getappdata(handles.uibuttongroup3,'BathWall');
% Floor = get(handles.Floor,'value')
HomeName = get(handles.HomeName,'string');

Base = get(handles.BaseSqFt, 'string');
BaseSqFt = str2num(Base);

TotSqFt = BaseSqFt .* Floor; 

Perim = (((BaseSqFt .^ .5) .* 4) .* Floor);
Perim2 = (BaseSqFt .^ .5) .*4;
Perim3 = (BaseSqFt .^ .5);

WallLnFt_01 = Perim + (BedWall .* 2) + (BathWall .* 2); % double side wall
WallLnFt_02 = Perim + BedWall + BathWall; % one side wall

IntDoor = (BedRoom .* 2) + (BathRoom) + 2; 
Tile = ceil(BathSq/17.44287); 
Thinset = BathRoom + 1; 

Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

The Error Messages:

```
Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in cur2str (line 75)
t(1,:) = [];

Error in HomeBuilding>GoBut_Callback (line 267)
EstMat = cur2str(EstMat1,2);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in HomeBuilding (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in       @(hObject,eventdata)HomeBuilding('GoBut_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Are the variables `BathWall`, `BathSq` and `BathRoom` initialised (for example in the guy `OpeningFunction`?

Comment: I have not done anything with the `OpeningFcn`.  What is listed above is all that I have done. I am new to matlab and am looking to learn. I am going to edit the original question with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You use `setappdata` to store variables for later use in `uibuttongroup3_SelectionChangedFcn`. The problem is that this is done only in that function. That means the the variables are not stored until `uibuttongroup3_SelectionChangedFcn` is called, which happens only when the radio buttons are played with as you said.
When the GUI opens, the variables are not defined yet. Therefore you should define the three variables in `OpeningFcn` with some default value, or make sure that the user set the buttons before hitting go.

Comment: Right now the GUI selections are defaulted on the first choice for each panel. Is there a way I can remove the selection so the user is forced to choose one initially? (in place of having to cycle through the buttons)

Comment: As I said, you should add the default to the `OpeningFcn` so that no error is produced. If you wish to force user to select, set the default to something invalid (e.g. negative numbers) and check for parameters validity in the button callback.